# Docker file does not COPY files in subdirectories correctly when pushing to a local Balena device from Windows 10

Tags: docker, copy, dockerfile, subdirectory

I am writing a Typescript app that I want to run on several Raspberry Pis managed and deployed using Balena. My dev computer is running Windows 10. I am fairly new to Balena and Docker.

I am trying to compile my typescript in the Docker file, but the COPY command does not seem to copy files in subdirectories correctly when pushing to a Balena device running in local mode.

I have a very simple file structure as I have just initiated the project:

```
Dockerfile
start.sh
src/
- index.ts
- tsconfig.json
```

My Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM resin/raspberrypi3-node:10.0.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json
RUN npm i -g typescript
RUN JOBS=MAX npm install --production --unsafe-perm && npm cache verify && rm -rf /tmp/*

COPY . ./
RUN tsc -p src
CMD ["bash", "start.sh"]
```

When building and pushing the image to the Balena device in local mode I get the following error when the execution of the Dockerfile reaches the 'RUN tsc -p src' command:

```
[Build]   [main] Step 8/11 : RUN tsc -p src
[Build]   [main]  ---> Running in b843b59050da
[Build]   [main] error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'src'.
Some services failed to build:
        main: The command '/bin/sh -c tsc -p src' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Likewise I cannot cd to the subdirectory and just run the tsc command from there:

```
[Build]   [main] Step 8/11 : RUN cd src
[Build]   [main]  ---> Running in 7620e8a516f3
[Build]   [main] /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to src
```

I inserted a 'RUN ls' command into my Dockerfile before 'RUN tsc -p src' to verify the files are being copied which prints out the following:

```
[Build]   [main] Step 8/11 : RUN ls
[Build]   [main]  ---> Running in bf8b3c63454e
[Build]   [main] CHANGELOG.md
[Build]   Dockerfile
[Build]   README.md
[Build]   node_modules
[Build]   package-lock.json
[Build]   package.json
[Build]   src\index.ts
[Build]   src\tsconfig.json
[Build]   start.sh
[Build]   [main] Removing intermediate container bf8b3c63454e
[Build]   [main]  ---> 27ed6ea5eb9b
[Build]   [main] Step 9/11 : RUN tsc -p src
[Build]   [main]  ---> Running in 6ac5f86b5637
[Build]   [main] error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'src'.
```

At first glance it seems like the subdirectory is copied correctly but - correct me if I am wrong - ls should not be able to list files from subdirectories and it seems like the COPY command has somehow flattened the subdirectory. Honestly I am quit uncertain what happened.

Worth noting: the project compiles the TS just fine when just running 'tsc -p src' from the terminal of my dev computer and the files are copied correctly when pushing the project to a Balene device NOT running in local mode. It is when I push the project to a Balena device running in local mode it fails to copy files correctly.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?